# iOS 5 networking library

Tags: networking, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

What in your opinion is the best open source networking library to work with iOS 5?
I ask that, because the ARC problem with ASIHTTPRequest and AFNetworking is very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [mknetworkkit](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/)
It is ARC ready. And looks very interesting.

Comment: I've tested now MKNetworkingKIt. It is perfect. Thanks for telling about that! Here is a simple tutorial for using it: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/asihttprequest-is-dead-now-what/

Answer (score 2):

If you really need `ASIHTTPRequest` disable ARC for it.
Select your project -> Targets -> Build phases -> And set `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for files.
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/881989) for details.